# Sorting alphabetically ascending and descending using .sort()

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have created this basic use case of `.sort()` for my own reference. I am asking for a review to see if there are bad practices present or areas that could be optimised.

- Is my use of modifying the array correct? Do I need to place the newly sorted list into a new array?
- Using `.map()` I found it was parsing it as a string. Is `insertAdjacentHTML()` the right method to use here?

```js
const listArea = document.getElementById('listArea');
const btnAsc = document.getElementById('asc');
const btnDes = document.getElementById('des');

// The Original Array
let architects = [
  "Lloyd Wright",
  "Hadid",
  "Mies van der Rohe",
  "Le Corbusier",
  "Foster",
  "Gaudi",
  "Piano",
  "Gropius",
  "Niemeyer",
  "Aalto",
  "Saarinen",
]

// Empty Array to Store Sorted Array
let sortedList = [];

// Click Events for the sort buttons
btnAsc.addEventListener('click', () => sortAsc(architects));
btnDes.addEventListener('click', () => sortDes(architects));

// Sort the array in ascending order
function sortAsc(arr) {
  // Clear the sortedList array
  sortedList.length = 0;
  
  // Convert each item in the architects array to lower case
  for(const element of arr) {
    // Push these lowercase elements into the sortedList array
    sortedList.push(element.toLowerCase());
  }
  sortedList.sort();
  populateList(sortedList);
}

function sortDes(arr) {
  sortedList.length = 0;
  for(const element of arr) {
    sortedList.push(element.toLowerCase());
  }
  sortedList.sort().reverse();
  populateList(sortedList);
}

function populateList(arr) {
  // Empty out the listArea of all content
  while(listArea.firstChild) {
    listArea.removeChild(listArea.lastChild);
  }
  // Map each item in the supplied array to an li, and remove comma at end of each
  let listArchitects = arr.map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`).join('');
  listArea.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', listArchitects);
}

window.addEventListener('onload', populateList(architects));
```

```css
#listArea {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="asc">Sort Ascending</button>
    <button id="des">Sort Descending</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="listArea">
    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the things I'd point out in your code for improvements:

1. Arrays can be a const since you will not modify the array itself but just push new elements to the array.
2. In your functions `sortAsc, sortDesc`, you are iterating through `arr` just to make it lowercase and iterating through the array again in `sortedList.sort()`. In such scenarios, think about how you can reduce number of iterations.
3. `sort()` does in-place sorting, so no need to create a new array.
4. In function `populateList` by running `arr.map` you are creating another new array which I don't think is necessary.

```js
const listArea = document.getElementById('listArea');
const btnAsc = document.getElementById('asc');
const btnDes = document.getElementById('des');

const architects = [
  "Lloyd Wright",
  "Hadid",
  "Mies van der Rohe",
  "Le Corbusier",
  "Foster",
  "Gaudi",
  "Piano",
  "Gropius",
  "Niemeyer",
  "Aalto",
  "Saarinen",
];

function sortAsc() {
  architects.sort();
  populateList();
}

function sortDes() {
  architects.sort().reverse();
  populateList();
}

function populateList() {
  listArea.innerHTML = '';
  architects.forEach( (a) => {
    const list = document.createElement('li');
    list.innerText = a;
    listArea.appendChild(list);
  });
}

btnAsc.addEventListener('click', sortAsc);
btnDes.addEventListener('click', sortDes);

window.addEventListener('onload', populateList());
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="asc">Sort Ascending</button>
    <button id="des">Sort Descending</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="listArea">
    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, welcome to CR!

Answer (score 0):

Before going into more detail, I noticed the following:

- The convention for naming classes is to use `kebab-case`. Instead of `listArea` I would name it `list-area`
- Always use `const` instead of `let` unless you need to *re-assign* the variable. Your array is not getting reassigned
- When adding the event to the window you are actually *executing* the function instead of adding an event:

  ```javascript
  window.addEventListener('onload', populateList(architects)); // <- executes the function
  ```

  Also, the event is named `load` not `onload`. The reason why your code works is because the function is exectuted regardless of the event name being incorrect. So you are not actually assigning any event. It's a bug that happens to work.

  To fix this, you need to pass a function to the `load` event:

  ```javascript
  window.addEventListener('load', () => populateList(architects));
  ```

---

Now, the approach of using `insertAdjacentHTML` is ok for a few items with simple markup, but as the list grows I would consider sorting the existing elements in the DOM instead of removing them and re-creating the HTML from scratch:

````javascript
const ascButton = document.getElementById('asc');
const desButton = document.getElementById('des');
const listArea = document.getElementById('list-area');

const architects = [
  "Lloyd Wright",
  "Hadid",
  "Mies van der Rohe",
  "Le Corbusier",
  "Foster",
  "Gaudi",
  "Piano",
  "Gropius",
  "Niemeyer",
  "Aalto",
  "Saarinen",
];

// Create elements using the DOM instead of HTML strings
const architectElems = architects.map(architect => {
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.textContent = architect;
  return item;
});

function sort(order = 'asc') {
  const sorted = architectElems.sort((a, b) => {
    if (order === 'asc') {
      return a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent);
    }
    return b.textContent.localeCompare(a.textContent);
  });
  // We can append the same elements to the container
  // to reorder them without having to remove them from the DOM
  // and recreate the HTML
  listArea.append(...sorted);
}

ascButton.addEventListener('click', () => sort('asc'));
desButton.addEventListener('click', () => sort('des'));

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Add elements to list for the first time
  listArea.append(...architectElems);
});
```
````